# Program slowing down due to recursion

Tags: java, performance, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that adds every single file and folder name on my C: drive to an ArrayList. The code works fine, but because of the massive amount of recursion, it gets painfully slow. Here is the code:

```
public static void updateFileDataBase()
{
    ArrayList<String> currentFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    addEverythingUnder("C:/",currentFiles,new String[]{"SteamApps","AppData"});
    for(String name : currentFiles)
        System.out.println(name);
}
private static void addEverythingUnder(String path, ArrayList<String> list, String[] exceptions)
{
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("searching " + path);
    File search = new File(path);
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < search.list().length; i++)
        {
            boolean include = true;
            for(String exception : exceptions)
                if(search.list()[i].contains(exception))
                    include = false;
            if(include)
            {
                list.add(search.list()[i]);
                if(new File(path + "/" + search.list()[i]).isDirectory())
                {
                    addEverythingUnder(path + "/" + search.list()[i],list,exceptions);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was anything at all that I could do to speed up the process. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: <sarcasm>Have you tried defragging?</sarcasm> Why are you even trying to do this?

Comment: I'd venture in guessing the massive amount of string concatenation you're doing is not contributing to the speed of your program.  Using StringBuilders would probably help.

Comment: You are calling `search.list()` up to 5 times.  Even if the underlying FS implementation caches the lists, it still has to build the result list each time, which for large directories will add up.  You're only using one element, so save that the first time.

Comment: Why bother with ArrayList?  Use some sort of Set so your .contains can run in near constant time instead of linear time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Program slowing down due to recursion

No it isn't. Recursion doesn't make things slow. Poor algorithms and bad coding make things slow.

For example, you are calling `Files.list()` *four times* for *every* file you process, *as well as* once per directory. You can save an O(N) by doing that once per directory:

```
   for(File file : search.listFiles())
    {
        String name = file.getName();
        boolean include = true;
        for(String exception : exceptions)
            if(name.contains(exception))
                include = false;
        if(include)
        {
            list.add(name);
            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                addEverythingUnder(file,list,exceptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is (as of Java 7) a built in way to do this, [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29), which is much more efficient and removes the need to reinvent the wheel.  It calls into a [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) for every entry it finds.  There are a couple of examples on the FileVisitor page to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason for reinventing the wheel?
If you dont mind please use

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File, java.lang.String[], boolean)

Comment: Or better yet, with java 7, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html, if you want to do more than just listing them.

Answer (score 1):

> because of the massive amount of recursion, it gets painfully slow

While your code is very inefficient as EJP suggests, I suspect the problem is even more basic.  When you access a large number of files, this takes time to read from disk (the first time, reading the same again, and again is much quicker as it is cache)  Opening files is also pretty slow for a HDD.

A typical HDD has a seek time of 8 ms, if finding and opening a file takes two operations, then you are looking at 16 ms per file.  say you have 10,000 files, this will take at least 160 seconds, no matter how efficient you make the code.  BTW If you use a decent SSD, this will take about 1 second.

In short, you are likely to be hitting a hardware limit which has nothing to do with how you wrote your software.  Shorter: Don't have large numbers of files if you want performance.

Comment: +1 You've touched upon some really valid points here specially the cache. I am implementing a basic file search as we speak and would be benchmarking it with or without threads. (I need to see it for myself. Can't help it! :) Last time I had written it in C (running on a P4 1.7 GHz, a 7200 RPM hard drive) and I believe I had noticed a difference. What, your post has reminded me of is to reboot the system to clear up any disk cache that would otherwise skew the results.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Another option is to access a data set larger than the memory size. A reboot is the best approach.